# Set same properties to several labels

Tags: c#, properties

so I created some code like this:

```
label1.Text = "Test";
label2.Text = "Test";
label3.Text = "Test";
```

My question is, can you somehow put "Text" to all three labels at the same time?

Like this (doesn't work of course)

```
label1.Text & label2.Text & label3.Text = "Test";
```

Comment: Label1.Text = Label2.Text = Label3.Text = "Your Text";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set like this

```
label1.Text = label2.Text = label3.Text = "Text";
```